# Resolving dependencies using restore and build

Tags: .net-core

I have several questions related to [project.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json), dependencies and the use of [dotnet restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-restore) :

1. Where are located the packages when doing `dotnet restore` according to dependencies declared in project.json?
2. I have seen that one can `dotnet restore --packages "myPackagesPath` thus specifying where to locate its packages, but how can `dotnet build' knows where to fetch the dependencies afterwards? I have not seen any part of the project.json that specifies it.
3. is project.json the way to go when creating new project in dotnet core?

Answer (score 1):

1: depending on your OS, it is in `$USERDIR/.nuget/packages/`

2: sorry, no idea on this one

3: yes, try it by doing: `dotnet new` it'll create a project.json

Comment: what about [the first line of this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/target-dotnetcore-with-msbuild) and [that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/)? Does it make sense to continue working on project.json related stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Answering question 2 (since @CaptainMat answered the others):

Running `dotnet restore` with the `--packages` parameter will create a file at `<Your.Dotnet.Project.Directory>/obj/project.nuget.cache`.  The `project.nuget.cache` file contains the paths where each package was saved during restore.  So `dotnet build` presumably reads `project.nuget.cache` to find where it was saved.

The contents of the file looks something like this:

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "dgSpecHash": "cb5yhEzNUCTzbh1NqPX+bh8d9KsTks7Z1nVUC7nCSTjMjwyYc5Rlwj7TSx1njWRrykjnltRBMw5id0Qu1F0UEQ==",
  "success": true,
  "projectFilePath": "/Users/josh/myRepo/src/coffee/lightroast/src/lightroast.WebApi/lightroast.WebApi.csproj",
  "expectedPackageFiles": [
    "/Users/josh/myRepo/src/coffee/lightroast/packages/azure.core/1.35.0/azure.core.1.35.0.nupkg.sha512",
    "/Users/josh/myRepo/src/coffee/lightroast/packages/azure.data.appconfiguration/1.2.0/azure.data.appconfiguration.1.2.0.nupkg.sha512",
    "/Users/josh/myRepo/src/coffee/lightroast/packages/azure.extensions.aspnetcore.configuration.secrets/1.2.1/azure.extensions.aspnetcore.configuration.secrets.1.2.1.nupkg.sha512",
    "/Users/josh/myRepo/src/coffee/lightroast/packages/azure.identity/1.10.1/azure.identity.1.10.1.nupkg.sha512",
    "..."
  ]
}
```